# Multilingual data reports in c#

Tags: c#, class, translation, rdlc, google-translate

I have some textboxes on my webpage.
I put some data(english language) in my text boxes and then on submitting the data is saved in my database.
Now there is button "Print"on my page.

On this print button i want to generate a report in portugese language.

Now how can i convert the data(english) which is in database to portugese language.

Please note that data is entered through textboxes so it is not a fixed data.

Please suggest

Comment: Take a look at Google API's

Comment: It will be hard to have this 100% accurate all the time...  Machine translation can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this but for instance you could use the Google translate api or some other translation API and just parse the data through that before producing the report.

It might not always result in good translations

Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq#access)